# When converting date, I get previous day

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a string into a date "*as it is*".

```js
const date = "8/16/2019"

console.log(new Date(date))
```

However, I get:

[image]

As you can see I get the prevous day. I was thinking that it might be a timezone issue, even though there is no timezone that I am converting it from.

Any suggestions how to convert is as it is?

I appreciate you replies!

Comment: It *is* a timezone issue. `2019-08-15T22:00:00` is `2019-08-16 00:00:00`, converted to your local time.

Comment: Thx for your reply! I would like to convert the date as it is, without "any timezone"!

Comment: So "without any timezone" - does that mean UTC time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your format is consistent, you could `split` on `/` and use [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC). Creating your `new Date` from that would ensure it's UTC.

```js
const date = "8/16/2019"
const [month,day,year] = date.split("/");
const utcDate = Date.UTC(year,month-1,day);
console.log(new Date(utcDate));
```

Comment: Apparently this is the only sane way given that even mainstream browsers do not implement the official specs for parsing dates correctly.

Comment: The funny thing with this is that I get instead of August, September. That`s my output: `"2019-09-16T00:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: @Anna.Klee Sorry! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const date = "8/16/2019"
console.log(new Date(date).toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "Asia/kolkata"}))
```

Note:- You need to add timezone

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```js
console.log(new Date("8/16/2019").toLocaleDateString('en-us', {timeZone: "Asia/Kolkata"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date("8/16/2019")` will create a date object using your current timezone. Add a `"Z"` at the end if you want your date to be in UTC.

```js
console.log(new Date("8/16/2019Z"))
```

### EDIT

It appears that Firefox is not implementing the parsing of [standard date format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). Unfortunately until recently how exactly was a date parsed was completeley based on heuristics and intrinsically non portable.

Looking at Firefox bug tracker seems the issue has been discussed but the problem is still present (some toolkit just works around by replacing `"Z"` with `"+00:00"` before calling the parser).

The only way to be sure on every browser is to parse the string yourself and build the date from the fields. I didn't notice because I'm using chrome instead (in both chrome and Node works as expected).

## EDIT 2

After more investigation seems the standard requires that:

- If you use `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssz` then you get what ISO format for datetime defines it to be. Also the syntax described in the standard is not very precise and for example is not clear to me if the time zone can be present when no time is present (Chrome says yes, Firefox says no).
- If you use another format then anything goes (so for example there is no string that is guaranteed to issue an invalid date response).

In other words `new Date("8/16/2019")` is not portable Javascript (with the meaning that you don't know what date / time / timezone you will get, if any). Either you parse yourself the date or you just live with what that version of that Javascript engine in that moment decides to give you.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Perhaps I'm misinterpreting, but `const date = "8/16/2019Z"` [will *not* work](https://jsfiddle.net/7nvp2dxu/).  It logs `Invalid Date`.

Comment: @TylerRoper: Depends unfortunately on the browser, see note. Seems that the only reliable way is to just parse the date fields yourself as the implementation of parsing a string into a date is allowed to do whatever it wants.

Comment: Understood, appreciate the clarification. Javascript never *was* lauded for its implementation of dates :P

Comment: @TylerRoper: True... at least partially it's because the definition of dates is totally absurd (I like a lot the idea of 13 months of 28 days each with a special 0-day as the first day of the year - and a double 00-day every four years with longer and crazier parties :-) )